# Intuition behind LHS of squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

I am reading the solution to the following problem:
Evaluate the limit of

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (\sin t)^x dt \right)^{1/x}$$

The first step was stating that for $t \in (0, \pi /6)$, $\frac{3t}{\pi} \leq \sin t \leq 1/2$. I do not quite understand the  $\frac{3t}{\pi} \leq \sin t$ part.

The next step is to evaluate:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (\frac{3t}{\pi})^x dt \right)^{1/x} \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (\sin t)^x dt \right)^{1/x} \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (1/2)^x dt \right)^{1/x} $$

And then by squeeze theorem, show that it evaluates to 1/2.

Can someone enlighten me on the $\frac{3t}{\pi} \leq \sin t$ part, or it is choosen retrospectively so that

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (\frac{3t}{\pi})^x dt \right)^{1/x} =\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } \left(\int^{\pi / 6}_0 (1/2)^x dt \right)^{1/x} $$

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\sin t\approx t$ for $t\approx 0$. But instead of a hand-wavy $\approx$ we need an explicit bound fro $\frac{\sin t}t$ here. Since the sine is concave on $[0,\frac \pi6]$ (or even on $[0,\pi]$), we see that the straight line segment from $(0,0)$ to a point $(a,\sin a)$ with $0<a\le \pi$ (and in fact for some larger $a$ as well) is always below the graph of the sine. 
In particular, the graph of the sine function over $[0,\frac\pi 6]$ stays above the line through $(0,0)$ and $(\frac\pi6,\sin\frac\pi 6)$. This line is given by $y=\frac {3t}\pi$.

Comment: There is a typo on your function $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the intuition.

Whenever $ 0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{6} $ we have $\sin t \geq \frac{3t}{\pi}$ since the graph of $y = \frac{3t}{\pi} $ is always under the graph of $\sin t$, for $t \in [0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$. See the figure below

$\hskip3in$[image]

Just notice that the slope of the line $y$ is $$\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{6}} = \frac{1/2}{\pi/6} = \frac{3}{\pi}$$